# Swift - Argument type does not conform to expected type

Tags: json, swift, generics, decoding, codable

I am trying to make a reusable JSON decoder in my Swift app, but am getting the following errors when running:

- *Argument type 'User.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'*
- *Argument type 'User.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Encodable'*

My code is below:

```swift
func decode<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, from: String) -> [T] {
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: from)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data!)
    return result!
}
print(decode(User.self, from: "data.json")
```

Thank you for assisting me in solving this problem.

Best Regards,
NG253

Comment: What is `User`? How is it defined?

Comment: User is defined: ```struct User: Codable {
    var name: String
}```

Comment: My JSON is: ```[
    {
        "name": "John"
        "age": 24
    },
    {
        "name": "John"
        "age": 27
    }
]
```

Comment: `func decode<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, from: String) -> [T] {` instead. Your method should be defined as such. because you are calling it with `User.self`, so, it's a `Type` you are passing as a parameter. Also, that's how is written the "original one": https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895189-decode

Comment: The app now builds, but when the method is called, the app crashes.

Comment: Which line? `try? JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data!)` should creates a crash if `data` is nil. `return result!` should creates a crash if `result` is nil: Invalid JSON, JSON is not an array. Well, since the JSON you gave isn't valid, it's missing comma for instance, it can be because of that. Instead of force unwrap and/or not catching `error` by silencing them with `try?`, do real do/catch.

Comment: Do at least: https://pastebin.com/EpSrsi6k and read the errors!

Comment: I have edited my JSON so that it is valid, but the app still crashes on the let result line. - ```[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 24
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "age": 28
    }
]
```

Comment: Please catch and read the errors. Share them with us if you don't understand them. Else, it's like seeing a warning on your car, do not care about it, and when your car can't run anymore, asking why it doesn't work. There were warnings signs: Missing oil, low battery, etc.

Comment: Did you check the pastebin I gave? Also, there should be more info in the console, you are not showing it all.

Comment: Ok. This is the error: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the line that declares ```result``` I have checked my JSON on a JSON checker website, and all is good with the JSON.

Comment: Seems more like an error due to the use of a `!`. It's not a caught error with a `do/catch` as I gave in the previous linked pastebin

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass the type as an argument if the return type is known to the compiler

Here is my version (using a local string)

```
func decode<T: Decodable>(from: String) throws -> [T] {
    //let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: from)
    //let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    let data = from.data(using: .utf8)!
    return try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data!)
}

struct User: Decodable {
    let name: String
}

let str = """
   [{"name": "abc"}]
"""

do {
    let users: [User] = try decode(from: str)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```